# Progress Bar progression while saving a StringGrid

Tags: delphi

I am developing a program and I have a StringGrid on it; when a particular button is pressed, my program saves the stringgtid into c:\myfolder\tab9.txt. I would like to put a progress bar that indicate how many time remains at the end of the saving process because sometime the grid has a lot of rows and it could take some time. I am using this code:

```
procedure SaveSG(StringGrid:TStringGrid; const FileName:TFileName);
var
  f:    TextFile;
  i,k: Integer;
begin
  AssignFile(f, FileName);
  Rewrite(f);
  with StringGrid do
  begin
    Writeln(f, ColCount); // Write number of Columns
    Writeln(f, RowCount); // Write number of Rows
    for i := 0 to ColCount - 1 do  // loop through cells of the StringGrid
      for k := 0 to RowCount - 1 do
         Writeln(F, Cells[i, k]);
        end;
  CloseFile(F);
end;
```

I call the procedure in this way: `SaveSG(StringGrid1,'c:\myfolder\myfile.txt');`. My problem is that I don't understand how to do a progress bar that indicate the progress of the saving. At the moment I've only declared `ProgressBar1.Position:=0` and `ProgressBar1.Max:=FileSize`. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: If you want to do this *properly*, you should load the file in its own thread, and then send messages to the progress bar at regular intervals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How many cells are we talking about? Your main bottleneck is that you're writing to file for each cell, instead doing buffered writing.

I suggest that you fill TStringList with data from TStringGrid, and use TStringList.SaveToFile() method.

I've tested following procedure on StringGrid with 10,000,000 cells (10,000 rows x 1,000 columns), and it saves data to disk in less than one second:

```
procedure SaveStringGrid(const AStringGrid: TStringGrid; const AFilename: TFileName);
var
  sl    : TStringList;
  C1, C2: Integer;
begin
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  try
    sl.Add(IntToStr(AStringGrid.ColCount));
    sl.Add(IntToStr(AStringGrid.RowCount));
    for C1 := 0 to AStringGrid.ColCount - 1 do
      for C2 := 0 to AStringGrid.RowCount - 1 do
        sl.Add(AStringGrid.Cells[C1, C2]);
    sl.SaveToFile(AFilename);
  finally
    sl.Free;
  end;
end;
```